# How do you place a title on a background event in Jquery Fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to place a title on a background event in jquery fullcalendar, but it does not show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think fullcalendar supports doing that natively but you can use eventRender to achieve something https://jsfiddle.net/b8n110fm/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'prev, next'
  },
  events: [{
    start: '2016-02-01',
    end: '2016-02-10',
    title: 'Testing background event',
    rendering: 'background'
  }, {
    start: '2016-02-01',
    end: '2016-02-10',
    title: 'Testing regular event'
  }],
  eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    /* Only muck about if it is a background rendered event */
    if (event.rendering == 'background') {
      var bgEventTitle = document.createElement('div');
      bgEventTitle.style.position = 'absolute';
      bgEventTitle.style.bottom = '0';
      /* bgEventTitle.classList.add('fc-event'); */
      bgEventTitle.innerHTML = /*'<span class="fc-title">' + */ event.title /* + '</span>'*/ ;
      /* set container element positioning to relative so the positioning above will work */
      element.css('position', 'relative').html(bgEventTitle);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I put it on the bottom of the cells to keep it out of the days of the month when rendered in the month view. If there are multiple events in a cell it could get covered up - you may want or need to use eventLimit to prevent it. Example https://jsfiddle.net/b8n110fm/2/

Comment: For some reason, if I apply this to my code, my background events disappear but I can see the label just fine. Any ideas what this might be happening?